# Magento search not returning all results

Tags: magento, search

we are having an issue with Magento search were it only returns a few of the many results it should.  I have one search term where it returns 2 results but in the table  catalogsearch_result, there are 44 records for the search term.

I'm not sure where to look to resolve this.  Has anyone else seen this issue before or know where to look?

I've got caching disabled and have cleared and reindexed the search index.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've determined the issue a bug in Magento.

If you have a product in multiple categories and one of the categories has permissions set to not display to the group of the user, then the product won't display in any search results.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on this. What does 'Set to not display to the group of the user'
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Search Type` in Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.  Try changing it from `Like` to `Fulltext` or vice-versa.

Comment: I switched it to fulltext and it displayed 177 results, switching it back to like displays 2 results.

Comment: Are you searching for 1 specific word or a phrase?

Comment: two words in this case.  I also have similar issues when searching one word terms

Answer (score 0):

How about the advanced search, does that return the same number of results? If so, it is a configuration/indexing/caching issue. If not, you should check your installed modules in case one of them is hijacking the search functionality.